# When a group $G$ acts on itself (on the left) by $\rho(g,h) = gh$, why do the orbits partition $G$?

Tags: group-theory

This is probably an obvious question but I probably don't understand the concepts correctly.

Say a finite group $G$ acts on itself (on the left) by $\rho(g,h) = gh$.

From my understanding, the orbits in $G$ under the action of $G$ should partition $G$. But for example we have $G \cdot e_{G} = G$, so the orbit of $e_{G}$ is the whole of $G$. But then this would mean that if $G$ is partitioned by orbits, the orbits of the other elements would be empty.

Should it instead say that the distinct orbits of under a group action partition the set acted on? In that case it works, because in the above case the orbit of any element in $G$ is $G$, so there is only one distinct orbit, which does partition $G$ (so I guess the action is transitive in this case?)

Comment: All of the other orbits are equal to $G$, too.  The *distinct* orbits partition.  There just happens to be only one orbit here.

Comment: (Everyone knows this, so the "distinct" is often omitted in writing and conversation.)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense now. Got it, thanks!

Comment: Note that in any action of a group, distinct orbits are disjoint.